# How I can to create gridView with horizontal flickable direction and LeftToRight layout direction?

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

I am new in `Qt` , I want to know if is possible to create a grid View with horizontal `flickDirection` and the layout direction set to `LeftToRight` .

this is my code with GriView that I have created

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height:1280
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    GridView {
        id:grid
        width:parent.width*0.95 ; height: parent.height*0.90
        verticalLayoutDirection: Grid.TopToBottom
        layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight
        anchors.horizontalCenter :parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        clip: true
        model: 11
        cellWidth: width/3;
        cellHeight: height/3
        delegate:Item  {
            width: grid.cellWidth
            height: grid.cellHeight

            Rectangle {
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
                width: parent.width*0.75
                height: parent.height*0.75

                Text {
                    id: name
                    text: index.toString()
                    font.pointSize: 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with these two image I hope to explain myself better

**First image:**

[image]

**Second image:**

[image]

Comment: What do those images indicate?

Comment: The images indate how i want to create the grid , the 2th image indicate the grid after i scroll horizontaly the grid, i hope i was clear... Is there a different way to do it than the grid?

Comment: My question is in the sense that you indicate what you expect, what is wrong with the output you get?

Comment: with the code the i have posted i getting a gridview with vertical flick and 9th and 10th items are on the bottom , but i want that these are on right of the other items like in the 2th image...

Comment: Use `flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this number order isnt easy to get without some paging functions.
This is closest.

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height:1280
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    GridView {
        id:grid
        width:parent.width*0.95 ; height: parent.height*0.95
        verticalLayoutDirection: Grid.TopToBottom
        layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight
        flow: Grid.TopToBottom
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: 11
        cellWidth: width/3;
        cellHeight: height/3
        flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick

        delegate:Item  {
            width: grid.cellWidth
            height: grid.cellHeight

            Rectangle {
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
                width: parent.width*0.75
                height: parent.height*0.75

                Text {
                    id: name
                    text: index.toString()
                    font.pointSize: 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```